# WooCommerce - How to create multiple single product template based on category?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hello I am fairly new to woocommerce, My shop has four categories of products which use same single-product template. I want to add a fifth category of products where the product page layout is very different from already the one used.

Here's the file structure -

- theme/woocommerce/single-product/
- theme/woocommerce/single-product-mock/
- theme/woocommerce/single-product-mock/title.php
- theme/woocommerce/content-single-product-mock.php
- theme/woocommerce/single-product.php

I created a file called content-single-product-mock.php. In single-product.php using the following code

```
        <?php if (has_term( 'mock', 'product_cat' )) {
            woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-mock' );
        } else{
         wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); 
        } ?>
```

For the category mock it redirects to content-single-product-mock.php, but it uses the template files in single-product folder. How do change the template path in content-single-product-mock.php so that it uses the customized files in single-product-mock folder?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is probably more than one way to do this, but they all kind of turn around the idea of filtering the template before it is included.

You *could* totally skip WooCommerce's `simple-product.php` template (without needing to override that template) and go directly to `simple-product-mock.php` and create everything there. You'd do that by filtering [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include).

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'so_25789472_template_include' );

function so_25789472_template_include( $template ) {
  if ( is_singular('product') && (has_term( 'mock', 'product_cat')) ) {
    $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/single-product-mock.php';
  } 
  return $template;
}
```

You could edit `single-product-mock.php` to call `content-single-product-mock.php` and hard-code *that* file. Nothing requires you to keep using Woo's hooks and functions. The point of them is just to make it easy for you to customize.

Or to be really tricky, you could duplicate templates such as `single-product/title.php` into a `single-product-mock` folder... ex: `single-product-mock/title.php` and then any time we're on a single product template in the mock category, we'll intercept calls to the `single-product/something.php` template and redirect them to `single-product-mock/something.php` *if* it exists and keep pointing to the `single-product/something.php` if it does not. We'll do this via the `woocommerce_locate_template` filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_locate_template', 'so_25789472_locate_template', 10, 3 );

function so_25789472_locate_template( $template, $template_name, $template_path ){

    // on single posts with mock category and only for single-product/something.php templates
    if( is_product() && has_term( 'mock', 'product_cat' ) && strpos( $template_name, 'single-product/') !== false ){

        // replace single-product with single-product-mock in template name
        $mock_template_name = str_replace("single-product/", "single-product-mock/", $template_name );

        // look for templates in the single-product-mock/ folder
        $mock_template = locate_template(
            array(
                trailingslashit( $template_path ) . $mock_template_name,
                $mock_template_name
            )
        );

        // if found, replace template with that in the single-product-mock/ folder
        if ( $mock_template ) {
            $template = $mock_template;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Update to filter `wc_get_template` instead.

```
/**
 * Change wc template part for product with a specific category
 *
 * @param  string $templates
 * @param  string $slug
 * @param  string $name
 * @return string
 */
function so_25789472_get_template_part( $template, $slug, $name ) {
  if ( $slug == 'content' && $name = 'single-product' && has_term( 'test', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    $template = locate_template( array( WC()->template_path() . 'content-single-product-test.php' ) );
  } 
  return $template;
}
add_filter( 'wc_get_template_part', 'so_25789472_get_template_part', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much. Ended up using woocommerce_locate_template filer. It works fine :)