# Woocommerce different template for products

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

I want to set different template for the relevant product category. I changed single-product.php file

```
   if (is_product_category( 'first-category' )) {
    woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
}else{
    woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-other' );
}
```

Still is loading content-single-product-other.php file content. I'm sure that the category of the product is checked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WooCommerce - How to create multiple single product template based on category?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789472/woocommerce-how-to-create-multiple-single-product-template-based-on-category)

Comment: I thought this sounded familiar, please see my answer to the  duplicate question. The problem is that `is_product_category()` tests if you are ON a product category archive and not whether a product is IN a particular category. For the latter you need the WordPress function [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it can happen if you have putted single-product-other.php in (yourtheme/woocommerce/) folder and single-product.php in plugin folder.
All you have to do is put both template in your theme's woocommerce folder(it is the proper way to customize original code).

still if it does not work then try to replace your code

woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );

with this.
wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );

Answer (score 0):

Replying to helgatheviking input. As mentioned the `is_product_category()` call refers to a categories `archive` page and not a product assigned to the category type. Here's my working example for a composite product. Replace `YourCategory`with the `slug` of your category

```
<?php
    if (has_term('YourCategory', 'product_cat')) {
        echo 'composite';
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'YourCategory' );
    }else{
        echo 'default';
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
    } ?>
```