# WooCommerce - How to create separate single product template based on product category?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

I've been reading all these different questions and answers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789472/woocommerce-how-to-create-multiple-single-product-template-based-on-category/55664745#55664745) simply trying to achieve a separate template for an applied product category.

in my case, I'd like to use the product category 'fancy' (as opposed to 'mock') to load a separate template file. Maybe I wasn't understanding these answers fully but what I have currently is this in my child theme's function.php:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'so_25789472_template_include' );

function so_25789472_template_include( $template ) {
  if ( is_singular('product') && (has_term( 'fancy', 'product_cat')) ) {
    $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/single-product-fancy.php';
  } 
  return $template;
```

and it simply doesn't work. I have single-product-fancy.php and content-single-product-fancy.php in my child-theme/woocommerce/ folder.

single-product-fancy.php has this on line 37:

```
wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-fancy' );
```

and content-single-product-fancy.php has my separate template layout

I had other variations that seemed to work but then would load a blank white page for the homepage, i think because of php error, not entirely sure.

can someone please help me figure out what it is i'm not doing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out using this:

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_template_part', 'so_25789472_get_template_part', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Change wc template part for product with a specific category
 *
 * @param  string $templates
 * @param  string $slug
 * @param  string $name
 * @return string
 */
function so_25789472_get_template_part( $template, $slug, $name ) {
  if ( $slug == 'content' && $name = 'single-product' && has_term( 'fancy', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    $template = locate_template( array( WC()->template_path() . 'content-single-product-fancy.php' ) );
  } 
  return $template;
}
```